# swift prepareforsegue with mmdrawercontroller

Tags: ios, swift, variables, segue, mmdrawercontroller

I have searched every where to find a solution to this error i am getting, i have also tried to use, nsuserdefaults, struct and global var to pass on my vars to other viewcontrollers. I am use mmdrawer and i have set a navigationcontrol on my first viewcontroller that who i named userOview and identifier membersArea. Whenever i try to use prepareforsegue i am getting the following error

```
Could not cast value of type 'xxxxxxxx.DjInformation' (0x115da8) to 'UINavigationController' (0x3ad405e0).
```

My appdelegate looks like this

```
    import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var centerContainer: MMDrawerController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.



        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int

        if (isLoggedIn == 1){

        var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController

        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        var centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("memberArea") as! userOverview

        var leftViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController

        var rightViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightSideViewController")as! RightSideViewController

        var leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController)
        var centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
        var rightNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rightViewController)

        centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav,rightDrawerViewController:rightNav)

        centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
        centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

        window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

         UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.None)

        }

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "bfd.Be_Fit_Donate" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1] as! NSURL
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Be_Fit_Donate", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Be_Fit_Donate.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and the view controller i am trying to send the prepareforsegue from is as follows

```
    import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import Foundation
import Social

public var AudioPlayer = AVPlayer()
public var SelectedSongNumber = Int()
public var TrackName = String()
public var TrackImage = String()
public var TrackDJ = String()


class MusicListTableViewController: UITableViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var songName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!    
    @IBOutlet weak var trackDjName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageArtwork: UIImageView!



    var trackName = [String]()
    var artistLabel = [String]()
    var trackUrl = [String]()
    var artWork = [String]()
    var tags = [String]()
    var artistId = [String]()
    var djInfo = ""


    @IBAction func facebookButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
            var facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            facebookSheet.setInitialText("Share on Facebook")
            self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
    @IBAction func tritterButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter){
            var twitterSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
            twitterSheet.setInitialText("Share on Twitter")
            self.presentViewController(twitterSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Twitter account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func myPlayList(sender: UIButton) {
        var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myMusicList") as! myMusicList

        var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Right, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func favoriteButton(sender: UIButton) {

         var  favSong = trackName[SelectedSongNumber]

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Nummer Toegevoegd"
        alertView.message = "Het nummer \(favSong) is nu toegevoegd aan uw favorieten muziek lijst"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    }

    @IBAction func djInformation(sender: UIButton) {

        var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("djInformation") as! DjInformation

        var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Right, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

           var artist_label = artistLabel[SelectedSongNumber]

        if (segue.identifier == "djInformation" ){
            var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let targetController = detailVC.topViewController as! DjInformation
            targetController.djInfo = "hello"

        }
    }

    func getMusicListJSON(){
        let urlString = "http://xxxxxxxxxx"
        let urlEncodedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let url = NSURL( string: urlEncodedString!)
        var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, innerError) in
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            let musicArray = json.arrayValue

            //NSLog("\(json)")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                for musiclist in musicArray
                {
                    let track_name = musiclist["track_name"].stringValue
                    let artist = musiclist["artist"].stringValue
                    let track_url = musiclist["track_url"].stringValue
                    let art_work = musiclist["artwork"].stringValue
                    let track_tags = musiclist["tags"].stringValue
                    let artist_id = musiclist["artist_id"].stringValue
                    //println( "track_name: \(track_name) artist: \(artist) track_url: \(track_url) artwork: \(art_work) track_tags: \(track_tags) artist_id: \(artist_id)" )
                    self.trackName.append(track_name)
                    self.artistLabel.append(artist)
                    self.trackUrl.append(track_url)
                    self.artWork.append(art_work)
                    self.tags.append(track_tags)
                    self.artistId.append(artist_id)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    return
                })
            })

        }

        task.resume()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getMusicListJSON()

        playButton.addTarget(self, action: "playButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.7)

        playButton.hidden = true

        var error: NSError?
        var success = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
            AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,withOptions: .DefaultToSpeaker, error: &error)
        if !success{
            NSLog("Failed to set audio session category, Error: \(error)")
        }
    }



    func playButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){
        // set play image to pause wehen video is paused and also back

        if AudioPlayer.rate == 0
        {
            AudioPlayer.play()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        } else {
            AudioPlayer.pause()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        }
    }


    @IBAction func slideOutMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left,  animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func musicMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Right,  animated: true, completion: nil)
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }




    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return trackName.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("playerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! playerTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.artistName.text = trackName[indexPath.row]
        cell.trackName.text = artistLabel[indexPath.row]
        return cell



    }
    // set the song to play according to the table row selected. Also set the name and artist.
    func playSong() {

        var playnumber = trackUrl[SelectedSongNumber]
        var TrackName = trackName[SelectedSongNumber]
        var TrackImage = artWork[SelectedSongNumber]
        var TrackDJ = artistLabel[SelectedSongNumber]
        var DjId = artistId[SelectedSongNumber]

        AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: playnumber))

        AudioPlayer.play()
        songName.text = TrackName
        trackDjName.text = TrackDJ
        load_artwork(TrackImage)
        playButton.hidden = false


            }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

      SelectedSongNumber = indexPath.row
        playSong()


    }

    // set the song artwork to display in the player for the current playing song.
    func load_artwork(urlString: String){
        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.imageArtwork.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
    })
}
}
```

These are the two codes that i think should be the cause of the problem. But so far i can't find any way to pas any variables and i will be needing that to complete my app. What am i doing wrong here?

I can really use some help here to get this to work. Maybe my navigation controller is correctly setup. As the first viewcontroller should be embedded in it. But i am not sure i have done that properly.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution which was very simple if you know what you should do. When you are using mmdrawer and would like to send over data you could just create a prepareforsegue, but you also need to create a segue with overrides the mmdrawer. I find that you use you use the following just like you would do with prepareforsgue

```
@IBAction func djInformation(sender: UIButton) {

var artist_label = artistLabel[SelectedSongNumber]

        var centerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("djInformation") as! DjInformation

centerViewController.djINfo = "\(artist_label)"
        var centerNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = centerNavController
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Right, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

so basically what you do in prepareforsegue you can also do in button that is initiating the mmdrawercontroller.

Hope this makes sense and helps some one else. I am in no way a pro and i am not sure if this is proper or more something like a hack. but it fast and easy.